# Why primitive datatypes are not allowed in java.util.ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing primitive values in a Java collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504959/storing-primitive-values-in-a-java-collection)

ArrayList accepts only reference types as its element, not primitive datatypes.
When trying to do so it produces a compile time error.

What is the concept behind this? It seems like a limitation, is it not?

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504959/storing-primitive-values-in-a-java-collection)

Comment: ... which is itself a special case of [why you can't use primitive types with generics in general](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types).  Though in the pre-generics era, you still couldn't use primitive types with Collections, because there is no common base type for primitives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All collection classes of java store memory location of the objects they collect. The primitive values do not *fit in* to the same definition.
To circumvent this problem, JDK5 and onwards have **autoboxing** - wherein the primitives are converted to appropriate objects and back when they are added or read from the collections. Refer to the [official JDK tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) on this topic.

Checking the [JDK5 source code for ArrayList](https://github.com/eagle518/jdk-source-code/blob/master/jdk5.0_src/j2se/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) helps better understanding: creating an `ArrayList<E>` includes casting an `Object[]` array to `E[]`.

Answer (score 5):

Because Java can only use class (and not primitive types) and arrays (also arrays for primitives) for generics (between < and >).

List list; That is also a reason why there are wrapper classes for primitive types:

> int -> Integer
>
> boolean -> Boolean
>
> double -> Double
>
> byte -> Byte etc...

Comment: This isn't really an answer to why "Java can't use primitive types in an ArrayList because it can only use classes in an ArrayList" doesn't address why it can't use primitive types. Particularly when the question is worded to show the question asker understands it only accepts reference types.