# How can I use a map for calculations?

Tags: java, collections

I'm working on a program for class.  Using a TreeMap to store IDs (String - Key) and earnings  amounts (double - value).  I'm importing the values from a text file using a Scanner.  My problem at the moment is that I need the values to accumulate rather than overwriting with the last value read.  So my question is how do you use a Map to do calculations like that?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a new value to your map, if the key already exists, you can get the associated value, add the new value to it, and put it back into the map. Example:

```
// Assuming that key and value were read from your file, and that
// myMap is declared as "Map<String, Double>"
if (myMap.containsKey (key)) {
    double oldValue = myMap.get (key);
    value += oldValue;
}

myMap.put (key, value);
```

Comment: @thekashyap if it makes you feel better this code doesn't work for me as it is.  The second line gives an incompatible type error because the variable is a double but the key is a string...  I really wish spec docs were easier to read.

Comment: @StevetheMaker How did you declare your `Map`?

Comment: @Laf I just used: TreeMap agentMap = new TreeMap();  When I tried to specify types in the constructor I was getting errors that I couldn't figure out so I thought I'd give this a try.

Comment: You should use generics to declare your tree, so that you get type checking at compile time rather than errors at runtime. Your declaration should look like: `TreeMap<String, Double> agentMap = new TreeMap<String, Double> ();`. This is assuming that your key is a `String`, and your values are `Double`.

Comment: OMG...  I just wasn't capitalizing the word Double.  Why would that need to be caps sometimes and lowercase other times?

Comment: Capitalized means that you are using the class, and the lowercase means you are using the primitive type. Maps can only store objects, so in this case you need a `Double`, and not a `double`. Java will automatically convert `Double` into `double` and vice-versa (you can read more information on auto-boxing [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)).

Comment: @StevetheMaker it does make me feel better that it didn't work.. you also learned that you didn't know enough of template specialization (generics), implicit type casting (auto-boxing) etc. Java's javadocs are sooo much better to browse than man pages and C++ comments..

Comment: Well, I appreciate the hard-handed and the soft-handed approach.  I'm trying to get a degree online and I don't want a pile of certs and no ability to code when I'm finished (I'm at least past fizzbuzz at this point).  At the same time, I don't have a single human to bounce ideas off of, so SO and SE are essentially my classroom.

Comment: I wish to note some issue. For the first, why do you use TreeMap? It is a sorted implementation, its search takes O(log n) time. So, if you may consider using HashMap istead.

Comment: for the second, program to interfaces, so, never use concreate implementations when create a reference. Use Map<String, Double> agentMap = new TreeMap<String, Double>(); instead.

Comment: for the third, concerning performance issue, I would recommend to use primitive collections, you may read here for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504959/storing-primitive-values-in-a-java-collection

Answer (score 3):

There is no implicit functionality in `Map`. Idea behind your homework assignment is for you to learn how to insert, find, get and replace to/from a `Map`. There are functions for each of these and ou should use all to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

1) Check whether value with same key exists in the map
2) If it exists then read it and add the currently read value. Put it back into map