# Hashmap does not work with int, char

Tags: java, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing primitive values in a Java collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504959/storing-primitive-values-in-a-java-collection)

In java when I use the following :-

```
public HashMap<char, int> buildMap(String letters)
{
    HashMap<char, int> checkSum = new HashMap<char, int>();

    for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length(); ++i )
    {
        checkSum.put(letters.charAt(i), primes[i]);
    }

    return checkSum;
}
```

I get errors related to inappropriate types. I solved my problem by using Character and Integer instead of char and int respectively. However, I'm having trouble figuring out why HashMap fails to be able to deal with primitive data types.

Comment: Okay, everybody... the OP is asking [*why*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types).

Comment: @PaulBellora That duplicate is also about the why

Comment: How bizarre. Had always presumed char's wrapper class in Java would be Char.. Instead it's Character!

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Generic parameters can only bind to reference types, not primitive types, so you need to use the corresponding wrapper types.  Try `HashMap<Character, Integer>` instead.

> However, I'm having trouble figuring out why HashMap fails to be able to deal with primitive data types.

This is due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).  Java didn't have generics from the beginning so a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` is really a `HashMap<Object, Object>`.  The compiler does a bunch of additional checks and implicit casts to make sure you don't put the wrong type of value in or get the wrong type out, but at runtime there is only one `HashMap` class and it stores objects.

Other languages "specialize" types so in C++, a `vector<bool>` is very different from a `vector<my_class>` internally and they share no common `vector<?>` super-type.  Java defines things though so that a `List<T>` [**is a**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `List` regardless of what `T` is for backwards compatibility with pre-generic code.  This backwards-compatibility requirement that there has to be a single implementation class for all parameterizations of a generic type prevents the kind of template specialization which would allow generic parameters to bind to primitives.

Answer (score 18):

Generics can't use primitive types in the form of keywords.

Use

```
public HashMap<Character, Integer> buildMap(String letters)
{
    HashMap<Character, Integer> checkSum = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length(); ++i )
    {
        checkSum.put(letters.charAt(i), primes[i]);
    }

    return checkSum;
}
```

**Updated:** With Java 7 and later, you can use the diamond operator.

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> checkSum = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Generics only support object types, not primitives.  Unlike C++ templates, generics don't involve code generatation and there is only one HashMap code regardless of the number of generic types of it you use.

[Trove4J](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) gets around this by pre-generating selected collections to use primitives and supports [TCharIntHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TCharIntHashMap.html) which to can wrap to support the `Map<Character, Integer>` if you need to.

> TCharIntHashMap: An open addressed Map implementation for char keys and int values.

Answer (score 2):

Hashmaps can only use `classes`, not `primitives`.  This [page](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/difference-between-a-primitive-type-and-a-class-type/) from programmerinterview.com might be of use in guiding you to finding the answer.  To be honest, I haven't figured out the answer to this problem in detail myself.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put primitive types into collections. However, you can declare them using their corresponding object wrappers and still add the primitive values, as long as the boxing allows you.

Answer (score 2):

Generic Collection classes cant be used with primitives. Use the Character and Integer wrapper classes instead.

`Map<Character , Integer > checkSum = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();`

Answer (score 2):

`Generics` can be defined using `Wrapper` classes only. If you don't want to define using Wrapper types, you may use the Raw definition as below

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public HashMap buildMap(String letters)
{
    HashMap checkSum = new HashMap();

    for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length(); ++i )
    {
       checkSum.put(letters.charAt(i), primes[i]);
    }
    return checkSum;
}
```

Or define the HashMap using wrapper types, and store the primitive types. **The primitive values will be promoted to their wrapper types.**

```
public HashMap<Character, Integer> buildMap(String letters)
{
  HashMap<Character, Integer> checkSum = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

  for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length(); ++i )
  {
    checkSum.put(letters.charAt(i), primes[i]);
  }
  return checkSum;
}
```