# How to initialize a two column arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I need to create a List that records two columns {int, String}. I think ArrayList is what I need but I cant get my head around it. I pulled the Strings from a database and the int is the index value which I need to identify the strings position for later.

`List<List<String>> strArray = ArrayList<List<String>>;`

then could I do something like strArray.add().add() for each row I pull from the database?

Comment: If the ids are unique use a hashmap HashMap<Integer, String> else make a new class that the list can hold

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you should use a `HashMap` with `int` as key and `String` as value if your `int` values are going to be unique.

```
Map<Integer,String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
myMap.put(1,"ABC");
```

Note that as `Map` is a collections and java collections do not store primitive like `int`, they store objects so you have to use `Integer` wrapper class for your `int` values.

Refer this link [Why can Java Collections not directly store Primitives types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504959/storing-primitive-values-in-a-java-collection)

Comment: I didn't really know about HashMap before but I think ill use this, thanks!!

Answer (score 16):

Another approach would be to make a custom object:

```
Class CustomObject {
    int value1;
    String value2;

    CustomObject(int v1, String v2) {
        value1 = v1;
        value2 = v2;
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
List<CustomObject> myList = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
CustomObject o1 = new CustomObject(1, "one");
myList.add(o1);
// etc.
```

If the `int` values are unique and you want to consider them keys, then a `Map` would work as others have suggested.

Answer (score 7):

If you need just two values you can use native [Pair](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) class

```
List<Pair> mPairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();

Pair pair = new Pair(123,"your string");
mPairs.add(pair);
```

This will be a good decision if you int values are not unique and so you can not use HashMap

Answer (score 1):

If your IDs are not unique, you still can use Map :

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new IdentityHashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(new Integer(1), "string");
```

IdentityHashMap - use native hashCode implemetation for each OBJECT, so you don't need unique IDs, but you MUST create ALL Integers via operator 'new', and don't use autoboxing, because there is some [cache mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131136/integers-caching-in-java).

Also there is JVM parameter, which controlls cache size '-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax='.
But using this parameter you can't disable cache, if you set size to the zero, then cache will ignore it and use default: [-128; 127].
This parameter is only for Integers, there is no such kind of parameter for Long.

**UPDATE**
Also for non unique keys you could use some sort of multimap:
    Map> map

And store in it your values with nonunique keys:

```
map.put(1, new ArrayList<String>());
map.get(1).add("value1");
map.get(1).add("value2");
```

You can use HashMap for that for example.

Also you can find MultiMap implementation in google-collections: 'guava'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may wrap the int and string in a class, then put the class objects in List.

Answer (score 0):

> Map is an object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

I think it would be better if you use `Map<Integer,String>` where `key(Integer)` would be the index which will pointing to `String` value.

```
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
map.put(1,"str1");
map.put(2,"str2");
...
```

Comment: use sparse array for integer string combination.