# Return Arraylist of ints

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new to Java (1month). I've been trying to do the below unsuccessfully, any help would be appreciated. What I'm trying to have is:

1. Main passes int array to method **perm2**.
   `perm2(new int[]{1,2,3});`
2. **perm2** will make permutations of it and add to an ArrayList and return it.

This is what I have so far. As you can see it just prints out the permutations. 
Problem is I can't add them to an ArrayList and return.

```
public static void perm2(int[] s) {
    int N = s.length;
    int[] a = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) a[i] = s[i];
    perm2(a, N);
}
private static void perm2(int[] a, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        swap(a, i, n-1);
        perm2(a, n-1);
        swap(a, i, n-1);
    }
}  
private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int c;
    c = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = c;
}
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

I don't really want to output them with `sysout`. I just want them returned in ArrayList of int arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a return type of `List<int[]>` (or you prefer, `ArrayList<int[]>`) from the main perm method:

```
public static List<int[]> perm2(int[] s) {
    List<int[]> permutations = new ArrayList<>();
    perm2(permutations, s.clone(), s.length);
    return permutations;
}
```

Then in the second method, pass the list to it as another parameter so it can add each permutation. Note that it has to clone the array, otherwise it would be adding the same (changing) array object over and over, which would end up with a list of several copies of the final permutation only.

```
private static void perm2(List<int[]> permutations, int[] a, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        permutations.add(a.clone());
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        swap(a, i, n-1);
        perm2(permutations, a, n-1);
        swap(a, i, n-1);
    }
}
```

To call it:

```
List<int[]> permutations = perm2(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });

for (int[] permutation : permutations) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(permutation));
}
```

Something that's not necessary, but you might consider, is changing the parameter of the first perm2 method from `int[] s` to `int... s`. Then you could invoke it as simply `perm2(1, 2, 3)` instead of `perm2(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 })`, although it would still accept the explicit array too.

Comment: @blalasaadri `List<int[]>` is fine. `int[]` is an object, not a primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList can only hold objects. You can use wrapper class Integer for your int ([primitive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)) values.

Comment: See the similar question [Why can Java Collections not directly store Primitives types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504959/why-can-java-collections-not-directly-store-primitives-types)

Comment: But I thought int[] IS an object. (container object) no ?

Answer (score 1):

Your first perm2 method should at least return the new object. The original object isn't being modified in that code.

```
  public static int[] perm2(int[] s) {
    int N = s.length;
    int[] a = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) a[i] = s[i];
    perm2(a, N);
    return a;
}
private static void perm2(int[] a, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        swap(a, i, n-1);
        perm2(a, n-1);
        swap(a, i, n-1);
    }
 }  
private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int c;
    c = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the method perm2 to return the array and the signature of the methods.

```java
    public static ArrayList<Integer> perm2(int[] s) {
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        a.add(s[i]);
    }
    perm2(a, a.size());
    return a;
}
private static void perm2(ArrayList<Integer> a, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        swap(a, i, n - 1);
        perm2(a, n - 1);
        swap(a, i, n - 1);
    }
}
private static void swap(ArrayList<Integer> a, int i, int j) {
    int c;
    c = a.get(i);
    a.add(i, a.get(j));
    a.remove(i + 1);
    a.set(j, c);
}
```