# How to use a Map that has a primitive int key and a primitive int value?

Tags: java, android, performance, primitive

`SparseArray<Object>` is great a way to avoid autoboxing if you want to use a primitive key. What if you want to use a primitive value? Something like `SparseArray<int>` (if it existed)?

I want to make an `int` to an `int`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "make an int to an int". Anyway generic types can't represent primitive types.

Comment: Hey ZakTaccardi, this topic is already discussed in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504959/why-can-java-collections-not-directly-store-primitives-types

Comment: http://fastutil.di.unimi.it

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do it. Java does not allow primitive types to be used as type arguments in generic types. You'll have to use the wrapper type `Integer`.